# how to debug C++ dll called from C++ DllImport

Tags: c++, debugging, dllimport

I wonder if there is any way to debug c++ dll called from C++ DllImport in VS 2010. I tried to attach the project into c++ application but it didn't work - didn't stop at a break point.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If the dll project is in the same solution as your exe you can simple debug it by breakpoints. Make sure you compile both, so you have also debug dll and debug exe. Otherwise i think you can attach the debugger to the process which is using the dll... not sure, this case is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi @Mekon, the dll project is in the same solution as my exe, but i don't know why i can't debug the dll project. i try to attach but i find dll on list process, can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the solution which has the code for the DLL
2. Compile the DLL with debug symbols
3. Start the program that loads the DLL
4. Open "Attach to process" and choose the process of the program.

If the program has loaded the DLL you can now debug it.

Comment: i try to do flow your step, but it still not work for me.

Comment: I can't help you unless you provide more information. There are too many possible causes. Are you sure the DLL is compiled with debug symbols? Are you sure the .NET project loads the DLL that the C++ project compiles? Do you hit a breakpoint if you put one in the DLL's DllMain function?